# How to integrate Stata software with Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, integration, stata

Our client has Stata software (reporting software) version 12 and 13 with Oracle database. We need to fetch and pull data from Sharepoint  2013 to Stata software.

Anyone has any suggestions on how to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

There exists software that allows you to create an ODBC connection to sharepoint. Stata can then load and insert the data using the odbc command.